# UC_IMAGE_PATH Update Tool

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

I am using the Update Tool that is part of the GlassFish Server v3.  I received the following error:

> Update Tool was unable to start.
>   The Python runtime could not be found.
>   To fix this problem use the UC_IMAGE_PATH environment variable
>   to provide a path to a valid image.

I am unsure what to point this variable to?  I am trying to download Ant 1.7.1.

Thanks.

OS = Windows 7

Comment: It may be that I have Ant already installed or was previously installed.  The Environmental variable is set to find ant in a folder which has already been deleted.  Your suggestions appreciated.

Comment: My first guess is that the Glassfish update tool uses Python, and it can't find Python on your system. I don't think that Ant is the issue. Install Python and then tell us about your progress

Comment: I wish there was a selected answer for this... would be very ehlpful right now.

Answer (score 8):

Do you have AVG installed?  If so I recommend that you go to Options-->Virus Vault.  If you have something similar to:

```
C:\glassfish\pkg\python2.4-minimal\python.exe
```

Select it and click restore.  If this was your problem, you also need to add an exception (otherwise it will happen again):

```
Options-->Advanced Settings-->Exceptions
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me - it was not a virus protection - although I don't have the same AVG stuff - so if you've got that maybe
it wasn't a 64 bit thing - my machine has 32 bit OS (Windows) and 32 bit all around
I tried installing Python and setting up UC_IMAGE_PATH evnironmental variable to point to the
path where I install Python (C:\Program Files\Python of course)
and that didn't work either
So I uninstalled Glassfish, then reinstalled it AND unchecked the install upload tool option and the enable upload tool option (which the wizard does by default once you uncheck the install option)
I found no other way to get rid of this problem - you can't disable the upload tool after its install without running it and of course it can't be run unless you can get it to find the python you have on your system, and that won't happen using any UC_IMAGE_PATH setting
I haven't found anything about this in glassfish documentation so no fix there either

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and could solve it this way:

First I uninstalled Java EE SDK and JDK, I had to manually remove the \glassfish3 directory. Then I cleaned up my Java installations, particularly I got rid of a 32-bit JRE 6. I left the 64-bit JREs 6 and 7 on the machine.

Then I installed the JDK again and after that the Java EE SDK. At the beginning of this install I got a message saying it could not find the java runtime and that I should run the installation program with the -j parameter to specify the location of the java runtime. So I ran:
     C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\java_ee_sdk-6u3-windows-ml.exe -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"

The installation went all the way through, at the end I got a message that some configuration failed because another path could not be found (probably the not-specified path to a password file). The html reports though said everything was alright, everything installed and configured correctly.

Now I can run the update tool successfully. Looks like the Java 32-bit installation was in the way.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can occur when you already have python installed and then install JAVA (JDK,JRE etc).. 
I had python 3.3 installed already. As few posts above mentioned because of this python was not installed in glassfish/pkg/python2.4--- while installation of glassfish via JDK/JRE or some other java related thing

SOLUTION:

I just copied python.exe file from my previous python installation directory c:/python33/python.exe to  C:/glassfish3/pkg/python2.4-minimal/

so now python.exe exixts at above path and it does not throw an error.

I hope this solves problem for some of you :)

Comment: This may be a solution thought I did not tried. But when I compare before and after my installation, I notice python is not installed in pkg folder.

Answer (score 0):

Anti virus AVG blocked the Python update tool of my Glassfish 3 install and removed it!

Could something like this have happened here?

Answer (score 0):

this bugged me for AGES!!  I finally got it to work by installing Python 2.7 and running the updatetool batch file in C:\glassfish3\bin.  If you are using a proxy to connect to the net make sure its set during installation, if not uninstall and reinstall java EE SDK from the start menu-->program files--java EE sdk.  The batch file asks whether you want to install the update tool.  click yes then run the it from the admin console at http://localhost:4848

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error, you probably have the 64 bit of a JDK installed. Make sure you have all the same architecture - 64bit python, JDK's, and java EE sdk...but the EE sdk isn't at the normal EE download page unfortunately:

Download the 64bit java 6 EE update2 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-6u2-wjdk-6u26-409231.html)
Or Download the 64bit java 6 EE update3 with jdk 7 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-7u1-downloads-523391.html)

Gotta use the 64bit EE though if everything else is.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all existing installations - `glassfish`, `jee6`, `jdk`, `jre` etc. If not uninstalling, remove from registry. Then install in this sequence for 64 bit - jre7 public and set path, jdk7, jee6 sdk (with tutorial). Will install glassfish. This will add `python2.4-minimal` in package dir. It's bundled with jee6 only and we don't need to install separately. You will be able to run update tool without hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7:

1. Uninstall Python
2. Uninstall JEE6 SDK
3. Clear contents of GlassFish3 folder
4. Check JAVA_HOME runtime environment variable path. Should be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\jre
5. Install JEE6 SDK. Python-minimal and Glassfish will get installed with it.
6. Run the Update tool now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this steps worked:
1. Uninstall Python
2. Uninstall glassfish and delete its folder.
3. Turn the antivirus protection off, before starting the glassfish installation (in my case it was AVG)
4. Install JEE6 SDK again

Other info: My OS was windows 8. Firewall turned off initially.

Answer (score 0):

I did two things, I first remove my own python installation. Then remove glassfish3 directory totally. Then installed again, when install again, I unchecked install updatetool, and check it again, then enable update tool. Everythings works. One could find python2.4-minimal installed under pkg folder.